# Stuck with broken apt-get unable to update my VPS or do any installations

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

First time posting here since I've usually been able to go around and fix my issues with help of google, but this time I think I'm in a bit of a pickle.

I have a VPS running on DigitalOcean which I use for personal projects. I had it set up a long time ago, I think it was even pre-installed by DO for me, possibly.
It's running Ubuntu 14.04 so I decided it's time to upgrade it - big mistake.

I ran some casual updates with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` Before running `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

At one of these the problems started - it seems that `apt-get remove` is not able to remove old kernel version? But I might be misreading the information absolutely since, sadly, I am not that proficient with Linux updates.

I will try to list all of the command outputs I've read might be useful. Any tips on how to get out of this mess are appreciated.

**`df -hT` output:**

```
root@web:~# df -hT

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  487M  4.0K  487M   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     100M  344K  100M   1% /run
/dev/vda1      ext4       20G  4.7G   14G  25% /
none           tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none           tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     497M     0  497M   0% /run/shm
none           tmpfs     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

Seems I'm good with the space on the server

**`sudo apt-get autoremove` & `sudo apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove` output:**

```
root@web:~# sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic : Depends: initramfs-tools (>= 0.36ubuntu6) but it is not installed
                                 Recommends: grub-pc or
                                             grub-efi-amd64 or
                                             grub-efi-ia32 or
                                             grub but it is not installed or
                                             lilo (>= 19.1) but it is not installed
 linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic : Depends: initramfs-tools (>= 0.36ubuntu6) but it is not installed
                                 Recommends: grub-pc or
                                             grub-efi-amd64 or
                                             grub-efi-ia32 or
                                             grub but it is not installed or
                                             lilo (>= 19.1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

**autoremove with fix flag:**

```
root@web:~# sudo apt-get -f autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  bash-completion cloud-guest-utils coreutils dpkg ifupdown
  init-system-helpers initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core
  initscripts klibc-utils libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libapparmor-perl libblkid1
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libfdisk1 libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcrypt20
  libgpg-error0 libklibc liblocale-gettext-perl libmount1 libmysqlclient20
  libncurses5 libncursesw5 libperl5.22 libselinux1 libsmartcols1
  libsub-name-perl libsystemd0 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl
  libtinfo5 libudev1 lsb-base perl perl-base perl-modules-5.22 rename
  sysvinit-utils udev util-linux
Suggested packages:
  rdnssd libclone-perl libmldbm-perl libnet-daemon-perl libsql-statement-perl
  rng-tools perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl libterm-readline-perl-perl
  bootlogd sash kbd console-tools util-linux-locales
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libterm-readkey-perl libtext-soundex-perl linux-headers-3.13.0-79
  linux-headers-3.13.0-79-generic linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic mysql-client-5.5 perl-modules
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core libfdisk1 libgcrypt20 libmysqlclient20
  libperl5.22 libsmartcols1 libsystemd0 perl-modules-5.22 rename udev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bash-completion cloud-guest-utils coreutils dpkg ifupdown
  init-system-helpers initramfs-tools-bin initscripts klibc-utils
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libapparmor-perl libblkid1 libdbd-mysql-perl
  libdbi-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl libgpg-error0 libklibc
  liblocale-gettext-perl libmount1 libncurses5 libncursesw5 libselinux1
  libsub-name-perl libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtinfo5
  libudev1 lsb-base perl perl-base sysvinit-utils util-linux
32 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 8 to remove and 277 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/16.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 279 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 143659 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic (3.13.0-79.123) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-79-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-79-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-79-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools: 33: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools: update-initramfs: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic (3.13.0-79.123) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-79-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools: 33: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools: update-initramfs: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**`sudo apt-get -f install` output:**

```
root@web:~# sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  bash-completion cloud-guest-utils coreutils dpkg ifupdown
  init-system-helpers initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core
  initscripts klibc-utils libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libapparmor-perl libblkid1
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libfdisk1 libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcrypt20
  libgpg-error0 libklibc liblocale-gettext-perl libmount1 libmysqlclient20
  libncurses5 libncursesw5 libperl5.22 libselinux1 libsmartcols1
  libsub-name-perl libsystemd0 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl
  libtinfo5 libudev1 lsb-base perl perl-base perl-modules-5.22 rename
  sysvinit-utils udev util-linux
Suggested packages:
  rdnssd libclone-perl libmldbm-perl libnet-daemon-perl libsql-statement-perl
  rng-tools perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl libterm-readline-perl-perl
  bootlogd sash kbd console-tools util-linux-locales
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libterm-readkey-perl libtext-soundex-perl linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic mysql-client-5.5 perl-modules
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core libfdisk1 libgcrypt20 libmysqlclient20
  libperl5.22 libsmartcols1 libsystemd0 perl-modules-5.22 rename udev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bash-completion cloud-guest-utils coreutils dpkg ifupdown
  init-system-helpers initramfs-tools-bin initscripts klibc-utils
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libapparmor-perl libblkid1 libdbd-mysql-perl
  libdbi-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl libgpg-error0 libklibc
  liblocale-gettext-perl libmount1 libncurses5 libncursesw5 libselinux1
  libsub-name-perl libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtinfo5
  libudev1 lsb-base perl perl-base sysvinit-utils util-linux
32 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 6 to remove and 277 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/16.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 202 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 143659 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic (3.13.0-79.123) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-79-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-79-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-79-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools: 33: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools: update-initramfs: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic (3.13.0-79.123) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-79-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-79-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools: 33: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools: update-initramfs: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**`ls -l /boot` output:**

```
root@web:~# ls -l /boot
total 70752
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1165578 Mar 10  2016 abi-3.13.0-83-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   166221 May  9  2019 config-3.13.0-170-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   165918 Mar 10  2016 config-3.13.0-83-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   191071 Nov 13 22:00 config-4.4.0-170-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Dec 29 08:09 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20352301 Dec 29 08:05 initrd.img-3.13.0-170-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20176312 Dec 29 08:05 initrd.img-3.13.0-79-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   176500 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178176 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178680 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  3418683 May  9  2019 System.map-3.13.0-170-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3393725 Mar 10  2016 System.map-3.13.0-83-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3913902 Nov 13 22:00 System.map-4.4.0-170-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5909496 May 14  2019 vmlinuz-3.13.0-170-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5827776 Mar 10  2016 vmlinuz-3.13.0-83-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7208856 Nov 14 10:33 vmlinuz-4.4.0-170-generic
```

**`uname -a` output:**

```
root@web:~# uname -a
Linux web 3.13.0-83-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 00:25:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**`dpkg -l | grep linux-image` output:**

```
root@web:~# dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-170-generic          3.13.0-170.220                                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-77-generic           3.13.0-77.121                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic           3.13.0-79.123                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic           3.13.0-83.127                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-170-generic           4.4.0-170.199                                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic     3.13.0-77.121                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic     3.13.0-79.123                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                     4.4.0.170.178                                   amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

**`dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'` output:**

```
root@web:~# dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-=======================================-===============================================-============-===============================================================================
rH  linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic           3.13.0-79.123                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic           3.13.0-83.127                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-170-generic           4.4.0-170.199                                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic     3.13.0-79.123                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Comment: Can you show `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`  please?

Comment: @nobody I've added the output to the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so bad as I expected.
okay, lets try to repair that.

First of all make a backup from your important data, really.

Make sure you have enough space and inodes free.

```
df -h;df -i
```

Next step is to reinstall initramfs-tools. 
The command update-initramfs is not found, and is necessary.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall initramfs-tools=0.122ubuntu8.16
```

This is the xenial version according to package search, it lies in xenial-updates.

If it is not possible. Draw with wget the package directly

```
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools_0.122ubuntu8.16_all.deb
```

and install it with dpkg.

```
 sudo dpkg -i initramfs-tools_0.122ubuntu8.16_all.deb
```

Only, when this is running without error.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get -f install
```

Check with

```
dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'
```

if all packages are in clean state.
should be like mine.

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold                                                                                                                    
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend                                                                               
+++-=============================================-========================================-============-===============================================================================
```

then you can make your upgrade ready.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If something goes wired, let us know.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer got a downvote, but it was the answer that actually helped me get the server back to a somewhat usable state to actually do the upgrades. Thanks!

Comment: Fine. I am glad that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 transitioned to Extended Support Maintenance [in May 2019](https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-14-04-esm-support).  Kernel version updates are normally handled by a single metapackage rather than the specific versions being directly installed manually.  You should follow the [end of life upgrade instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/) from the Ubuntu community help wiki which describe how to upgrade an installed version that is now unsupported.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this has not really solved the issues I was having since `apt-get` still throws the same errors I've posted above.

Comment: @Pankucins Any other answer is pretty much off-topic for AskUbuntu.  You are using an End Of Life release.  If you want to stay on 14.04 you need to contact Canonical and pay for support.

Comment: I might've not explained myself correctly - I am trying to upgrade the version to a current release, however I'm unable to do that since I'm having the issues I've described above.